# Coloring R2 with two colors such that there exists no monochromatic curve

Tags: coloring

Suppose you have two colors, red and blue. Find a coloring scheme for points in $R^2$ so that there is no line segment or curve in the plane, no matter how short, that is all one color.

I believe there is a theorem that shows this cannot be done (i.e. any coloring scheme will have some line segment or curve that is all one color), but I don't know what the theorem is or the logic behind it.

Comment: How about the using the injection $I_Q$ of Q into R which is continuous nowhere, as a building block, and then mixing a pair of this function with a XOR operator ?  Ie, consider $f : R^2 \to \{0, 1\}$ such that $f(x,y) = XOR( I_Q(x), I_Q(y))$ That should give you a "continuous nowhere checkerboard", in a sense.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Axiom of Choice, it can be done.

The cardinality of the  continuous curves in the plane (single points excepted) is $\mathfrak c$, the cardinality of the continuum.  Let these be indexed as $C_\alpha$, $\alpha < \beta$, where $\beta$ is the first ordinal of cardinality $\mathfrak c$.  By transfinite induction, we produce disjoint subsets $A = \{a_\alpha: \alpha < \beta\}$ and $B = \{b_\alpha: \alpha < \beta\}$ of the plane such that $a_\alpha \in C_\alpha$ and $b_\alpha \in C_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$.  Colour $A$ white and $B$ black; any points not in $A \cup B$ can be coloured arbitrarily.  Then there are no monochromatic curves.